# Como Definir um tamanho maior para um TextBoxFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Estou usando a classe `form-control` do Boostrap, e gostaria de ter um *TextBoxFor* com um tamanho maior, como posso fazer isso ?

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Titulo do E-mail:", new { @class = "col-sm-4 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-6">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.strTituloEmail, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.strTituloEmail)
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Diego, tenta fazer o seguinte: *@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.strTituloEmail, new { @class = "form-control input-lg" })*. Dessa forma o bootstrap reconhece a classe a ser usada e aplica sobre o elemento. Era isso que queria ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode utilizar [HtmlAttributes](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/asp-net-mvc-labelfor-helper-with-htmlattributes) do próprio HtmlHelper do asp.net MVC.

Podendo simplesmente colocar um `style`, setando o `width` para o tamanho desejado:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.strTituloEmail, new { @class = "form-control form-control-custom", @style="width:1000px;"})
```

Resultado em HTML:

```
<input class="form-control form-control-custom" id="strTituloEmail" name="strTituloEmail" style="width:1000px;" type="text" value="">
```

Ou criando uma `class` customizada para seu estilo desejado, como por exemplo:

```
<style>
    .form-control-custom {
        width: 1000px;
    }
</style>
```

E posteriormente utilizar a sua `class` customizada juntamento a `class` do bootstrap. (Só não se esquece que seu estilo sempre deve ser carregado posteriormente ao do bootstrap, para sobreescreve-lo)

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.strTituloEmail, new { @class = "form-control form-control-custom"})
```

Resultado em HTML:

```
<input class="form-control form-control-custom" id="strTituloEmail" name="strTituloEmail" type="text" value="">
```

> Use a hierarquia do CSS a seu favor, lembre-se do que significa a sigla [CSS (Cascading Style Sheets)](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets), use o C.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar o *HtmlAtributtes*, e utilizar as tags html dentro de seu textBox.

No seu caso específico ficaria assim:

```
  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.strTituloEmail, new { @class = "form-control", style = "width:250px; height: 30px;"})
```

Desse modo você poderá alterar altura e a largura de se `TextBox` alterando os valores que estão no  `width` e no  `height`.

Você pode verificar a utilização neste exemplo: [dotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GYs2SE)

Answer (score 1):

Basta adicionar a classe e o tamanho nos *HTMLAttributes*:

```
Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.TeuCampo, new { @class = "form-control", style="width:50px;"}
```

Comment: Tentei fazer da forma que sugeriu mas mesmo assim nao funcionou deu erro.

 Descrição: Erro ao analisar um recurso necessário para atender esta solicitação. Examine os detalhes específicos do erro de análise e modifique o arquivo de origem apropriadamente. 

Mensagem de Erro do Analisador: "class" is a reserved word and cannot be used in implicit expressions.  An explicit expression ("@()") must be used.

Comment: use width: 50px !important; ou crie uma class css, como a resposta do @Fernando, também utilize !important após passar o tamanho em px

Comment: @Rod se você mantiver a hierarquia de seus estilos e importar seu estilo, ou declara-lo após a importação do bootstrap, o `!important` não é necessário.

Comment: @DiegoDias, só agora é que consegui cá vir. Já vi que tens respostar, ainda bem :)