# Customizar largura do TextBoxFor

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-3

Como alterar o tamanho do **TextBoxFor** ? Segui exatamente essa solução e não teve nenhum efeito no meu formulário: [[Como Definir um tamanho maior para um TextBoxFor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/53781/como-definir-um-tamanho-maior-para-um-textboxfor][1])

O arquivo CSS do Bootstrap está sendo carregado antes;

**HTML:**

```
@model Merc.Dominio.Entidade.Colaborador
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "COLABORADOR";
    Layout = "~/Areas/Administrativo/Views/Shared/_AdministrativoLayout.cshtml";
}
<style>
    .form-control-custom {
        width: 1000px;
    }
</style>
<input type="hidden" id="hidColaboradorID" name="hidColaboradorID" value="@Model.ColaboradorID" />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>COLABORADOR - EDITAR</legend>

            <fieldset>
                <label><u>DADOS PESSOAIS:</u></label>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Nome)
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Nome, new { @class = "form-control form-control-custom"})
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <label>CPF</label>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.CPFCNPJ, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <label id="RG" name="RG">RG</label>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.RG, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    </div>

                </div>
            </fieldset>

        </fieldset>
    </div>
</div
```

Comment: Não seria pelo fato de você estar definindo a class col-md-8?

Answer (score 1):

Note que o `style` do `input` está fixo em 250px:

```
<input class="form-control" id="Nome" name="Nome" style="width: 250px; height: 30px;" type="text" value="Benício Calebe Giovanni Araújo" />
```

Como é Bootstrap, apenas apague toda a informação de `style` que o tamanho do `input` é alongado até o maior tamanho possível de largura.

---

**EDIT**

`style="min-width: 100%"` não é uma boa forma de resolver. Você resolve o problema apenas para um componente, sendo que deveria resolver para a aplicação inteira.

[Veja também esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/117346/2999).

Comment: O Html da imagem estava desatualizada e eu a exclui, bom não sei porquê o tamanho do input não foi alongado, no entanto resolvi acrescentando este estilo **style = "min-width:100%**

Comment: Editei comentando sua solução.